# how to use the message parameter outside of the `messageCreate`

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am having trouble getting the definition of the message parameter outside of the `client.on('messageCreate', async message)` event. Because I use `discord-music-player` it has its own events which are outside of the `messageCreate` event and the bot now cant send the message when I trigger a `discord-music-player` event.
So, how do I pass the message event into a `discord-music-player` event?

Comment: Which specific discord-player event would this be?

Comment: there is a NPM package called 'discord-music-player' and also all of the events which send messages into channels wont send the message because message is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use a global variable. Declaring a variable outside the event will save the value.

```js
var lastMessage = null
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
  lastMessage = message
  //rest of your callback
})
//once a message is received, lastMessage will be the message object, updating on each message
```